# Error establishing a database connection on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

Following Google App Engine's instructions for creating a local WordPress development platform, I created the database and initial user using the instruction's MySQL direction:

I have created a user on SQL, created instances, allowed access but I keep getting the error

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

Below is my `wp-config.php` file:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Google App Engine') !== false) {
    /** The name of the Cloud SQL database for WordPress */
    define('DB_NAME', 'wordpresstest');
    /** Live environment Cloud SQL login and SITE_URL info */
    /** Note that from App Engine, the password is not required, so leave it blank here */
    define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/wordpresstest-1382:wordpresstest');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
} else {
    /** The name of the local database for WordPress */
    define('DB_NAME', 'wordpresstest');
    /** Local environment MySQL login info */
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
}
```

Below is my `app.yaml` file:

```
# [START env]
env_variables:
  # Replace project, instance, database, user and password with the values obtained
  # when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/wordpresstest-1382:wordpresstest;dbname=wordpresstest
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
# [END env]
```

When I run localhost on Google Cloud Launcher, still getting the error.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong off the bat, can you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost for your local environment?  That's what I see here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/blob/master/wp-config.php

Comment: @LeoFNaN, I tried using 127.0.0.1, but still getting the error. I also tried as another user but still got the error. How did you do it to make it work?

Comment: What error you are getting. Is your database user having permissions to connect database from your host. You need white list the your ip address in google sql console.

Comment: @Rams, how do I whitelist my IP?

Comment: in GUI click on instance then Access control then Authorization , add your ip address

Comment: @Rams, I am running the site locally, do I just use the local version of my ip or?